# The try block doesn't execute

Tags: android

Code:- The try block doesn't execute and if I extend Asynctask the app 
crashes and if I don't extend the Asynctask then the catch(Exception e) gives me an error msg - "android.os.NetworkOnMainThradException".

try {

```
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://apis.hofficedemo1.ondemandcrm.co/AppRequestAPI").openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.connect();

            con.getOutputStream().write( ("txt_username=" + txt_username).getBytes());
            con.getOutputStream().write( ("txt_password=" + txt_password).getBytes());
            con.getOutputStream().write( ("appMode=" + appMode).getBytes());
            con.getOutputStream().flush();

            //System.out.println(txt_username+" "+txt_password+" "+appMode);

            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            while ( is.read(b) != -1) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
            }
            con.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("IOException", "Some error");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Kindly mention the exception 
write e.printStackTrace() in catch block to see what exception is there and post it here

Comment: I don't know what is the problem with the try block. I tried various methods and understood that's there is some problem with the HttpURLConnection

Comment: Add  e.printStackTrace() in catch block to see what is the problem in try block

Comment: I guess you haven't included INTERNET permission in manifest ... :P

Comment: @MananGandhi: If the `catch` block is executing then an exception is being thrown.  Exceptions contain information about the problem that occurred.  Currently your code is ignoring that information.  The first step in correcting an error is to read the error message.

Comment: I have included the INTERNET permission.

Comment: Try to debug the code. You will help yourself.

Comment: I have added the screenshot for logcat errors as well

Comment: This is the error from my Logcat - "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Comment: Try to set minSDK to 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtime exception is parent of Io exception so when you put catch blocks in a order such that parent exception is placed;Any exception will be catched and executed in parent catch only. so it executes runtime exception:
remove runtime exception for an instance and see the diffrence

Comment: If I remove RuntimeException then the app crashes and I get a report - "Unfortunately, App has stopped"

Comment: First thing :"Unfortunately, App has stopped" =exception. Just seen your logcat  it is Network on Main Thread exception.Try doing network operations in asynctask.

Comment: Ok means i need to extend Asynctask?

Comment: Yes you need to perform network operations in async task ,volley or any library .read this blog for more information on threading and network operation http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html   mark answer accpted if it helped please.

Answer (score 0):

Add after try block so that we can see what exception is there.

```
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```